# Gaussian blur filter causes text above the affected image it to hide

Tags: css

I encountered a problem while trying to blur an image in `CSS` on my webpage: any element rendered above the affected image will hide during and after the procedure. How can I resolve the issue?

For more information about the problem itself, I posted a snippet containing an example featuring that exact problem.

```css
.placeholder {
  display: block;
  /* Align the content within the container near the center. */
  text-align: center;
  /* Calculate both the width and height of the element. */
  width: calc(100vw / 3);
  height: calc(100vw / 3 * 2 / 3);
}

.placeholder img {
  display: inline;
  /* Fill the entire parent element. */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* Adjust the way the image is fit into the parent. */
  object-fit: cover;
  /* Add a transition to the element whenever an effect will be applied to it. */
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.placeholder > p.article {
  display: inline-block;
  /* Calculate the desired margin of the element. */
  margin: calc(-100vw / 3 * 2 / 3 - 1em) auto 0;
  /* Align the element vertically near the middle. */
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* Adjust the readability of the text. */
  color: white;
}

.placeholder:hover img {
  /* Blur the image inside the container when the cursor is above it. */
  filter: blur(4px);
}
```

```html
<div class="placeholder">
  <img src="http://fennek.mobi/bilder/fennek-3.jpg">
  <p class="article">A lazy fennec.</p>
</div>
<p>Copyright © http://fennek.mobi/</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to `.imageLabel`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.imageFolder {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: calc(100vw / 3 - 0px);
  height: calc(100vw / 3 * 2 / 3 - 0px);
  border: 0px solid #444;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.imageBox {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.imageBox img {
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
.imageLabel {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: calc(0px - 100vw / 3 * 2 / 3) auto 0;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.imageFolder:hover > .imageBox img {
  width: calc(100% + 30px);
  height: calc(100% + 20px);
  margin: -10px -15px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
  filter: blur(4px);
}
.imageFolder:hover > .imageLabel {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<a href="">
  <div class="imageFolder">
    <div class="imageBox">
      <img src="http://tim.nikischin.com/library/gallery/087_Charlotte/_IMG4015.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="imageLabel">Charlotte</div>
  </div>
</a>
```